# Replace values in a column with values in another column if not missings

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
>     Date1           Date2          
>   01JAN2021           .
>   01FEB2021           .      
>   01JAN2021       07JAN2021
>   07MAR2020       09MAR2021   
>   08JUL2022           .
>   .........       .........
> ```

In other words when there is an observation in variable Date2 the observation in variable Date1 must be replaced by the one in Date2 as follows:

> ```
>     Date1                  
>   01JAN2021          
>   01FEB2021        
>   07JAN2021       
>   09MAR2021        
>   08JUL2022         
>   .........
> ```

Can anyone help me please? I tried merge but it does not replace. Maybe the right way could be to replace the Date2 column entirely with Date1 but I don't know how to code it. I tried to do:

> if date2-date1=0 then do date_new=date1 else date_new=date2

but it simply gives date_new==date2 with missings.

Best

Comment: you can use `missing` function. e.g. `if not missing(date2) then do... `

Comment: you mean on my attempt?

Comment: yes, if date2 is missing then use date1 value else use date2 value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this

```
data have;
input (Date1 Date2)(:date9.);
format Date1 Date2 date9.;
datalines;
01JAN2021 .         
01FEB2021 .         
01JAN2021 07JAN2021 
07MAR2020 09MAR2021 
08JUL2022 .         
;

data want;
   set have;
   Date1 = coalesce(Date2, Date1);
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than two date-*n* fields, you can use a reverse index variable list with `COALESCE`

```
data want;
  set have;
  date1 = coalesce(of date9-date1);
run;
```